# Capybara: HTTP Auth. after redirect

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I'm facing a problem with HTTP Auth after redirecting from another page.

So let's assume. In my test i will visit my url with e.g `visit('http://admin:password@url1')`. 
After doing some stuff on this site i click on a button and i will be redirected to another site (`http://url2.com`) which requires a http auth as well. Now I need to enter new credentials which are not the same as from url1. Selecting the element and filling it with input will not work. I'm using Ruby with capybara and firefox with selenium-webdriver. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using selenium-webdriver, after clicking on the button you can try

```
page.driver.send(:find_modal).authenticate(username, password)
```